# Spring JPA @ManyToOne save fails with duplicate key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Parents")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child")
    private Child child;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Childs")
public class Child {
    @Id
    String number;
}
```

For both entities I have a standard CrudRepository. At startup of the app I try to populate the database with this code:

```
@Component
public class TestFiller implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Autowired
    ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    ChildRepository childRepository;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Parent parent = new Parent();

            String childId = "CHILD" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            Optional<Child> childOpt = childRepository.findById(childId);
            if (childOpt.isPresent()) {
                parent.setChild(childOpt.get());
            } else {
                Child child = new Child();
                child.setNumber(childId);
                parent.setChild(child);
            }

            parentRepository.save(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ChildRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, String> {
}
```

But for some inexplicable reason this fails when a child is already present in the database:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "childs_pkey"
  Detail: Key (number)=(CHILD6) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:441) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
```

It almost looks like the entity returned by the findById method is not managed. Why is Hibernate/JPA trying to persist the existing entity?

**Edit: as per request I added the ChildRepository**

Comment: What is in your `ChildRepository`? Show the code

Comment: Maybe it is caused because no flushing occurres? Try to persist newly instantiated child before saving the parent: `child.setNumber(childId); child = childRepository.save(child); parent.setChild(child);`

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I tried your suggestion as well but it still fails with the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question:

it is caused by the CascadeType `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on the `Child` property of the `Parent`. Removing that fixes it.

Apparently JPA cascades the `PERSIST` operation to the Child as well, even though it could have easily known that the Child is already a managed and persisted entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of your String ID.
Can you please try with findOne() method it may help you.

```
String childId = "CHILD" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
Child child = new Child();
child.setNumber(childId);
Child childOpt = childRepository.findOne(child);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of `findOne` but it fails with the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

As per the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

> This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations
>   (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or
>   synchronization) on instances of Optional may have unpredictable
>   results and should be avoided.

so first try to get the object from the result and check if it is the expected value :-

```
  if (childOpt.isPresent()) {
           Child checkObj=childOpt.get():
           parent.setChild(checkObj);
  }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it is definitely the correct object